# Can not improve bulk delete

Tags: oracle

I am using Java with mybatis.

I have a query like this and I need to execute this for 2000 values on `key_b`. That means I need to run the sql for 2000 times. Which is reasonably slow.

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE key_a = xxx
AND key_b = yyy
```

Now I came up with another solution, this time I am sending 1000 values in `IN` clause for `key_b`. Which means only two query I am executing. I was expecting this one to be faster at least. But this seems to be even slower than the above one. Here is the sql.

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE key_a = xxxx
AND key_b IN (y1, y2, ... y1000)
```

For more information, the key_b is the Primary Key. And the key_a is a Foreign key and has an Index.

Another thing, I've tried to take out the session and make a commit after all the sqls are executed. But It didn't improve that much.

Answer (score 0):

### you can use temp table for this:

I mean if you have a table which has id column.

And then You can insert your values to that table like this:

```
insert into temp_table

select 1 from dual -- your ids 

union all

select 2 from dual 

union all

select 3 from dual

union all

......
```

after you fill your temp_table you can run just this:

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE key_a = xxxx
AND key_b IN
(
select id from temp_table
);
```

Comment: This insert into temp table for 1000 values is slow. I guess it is because at the end it generates a large sql combining with the `union all`. And then the delete it doesn't make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend sticking with 1st approach: called prepared Delete statement in a Java loop over id collection. Off course with ExecutorType REUSE or BATCH, so that statement is prepared once and run for every record.
Furthermore, I discourage trying to bind thousands of parameters.

Anyway, I fear this is the best you can do since Delete operation will check integrity constraints, probably update index, for every record. That is not "bulked".